# Design pattern to use for read only operations by stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns, .net-4.5

I am trying to refactor\redesign some code, but I am stuck at a point where I do not know how to proceed. I usually would use entity framework and create a repository and unit of work for the appropriate tables, but I am not using any tables in particular, only the results of stored procedures which are spread across multiple tables or done by dynamic SQL.

There are no create, update, or delete commands going to be used with this project. Would it be advisable to write what would be the return POCO for each stored procedure and create some kind of `IReadOnlyRepository`? Or would I just avoid the DAL all together and just read the results from a `DataReader` and incorporate it into my business logic?

TL;DR

Is there any point to using an O/RM when doing read only operations? If so, what is it and is the design pattern different from the standard Repository\Unit of Work patterns?

Comment: wish i understood what you are asking.

Comment: @TMcKeown, Sorry, I edited my post to try to clarify what I was saying.

Comment: You can still use EF with stored procs. And if you want it readonly you can override the Save method on your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use entity framework with stored procedures.

Generate a .EDMX file and map the stored procedures you need to access

For Example:

```
public override List<AdminUser> GetAll() {
        using (var context = new Scope_v5Entities()) 
            return context.getAllAdmin().ToList();
    }
```

In this example, getAllAdmin is a stored proc.

Since you already have the procedures in place this is the most efficient way to go about things in my opinion.

You can create your standard data access layer in code still like you would if writing queries against the tables directly in EF.